# Can we characterize homogeneous Sobolev spaces by means of Sobolev embedding?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

For $\alpha>0^{[1]}$, let $D^\alpha=(-\Delta)^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ be the operator defined on all Schwartz class functions $f$ as follows: 
$$ \widehat{D^\alpha f}(\xi)=\lvert \xi\rvert^\alpha \hat{f}(\xi), $$
the hat denoting Fourier transform. We have the following Sobolev inequality: 
$$\tag{Sob}\| f\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}\le C \| D^\alpha f\|_{L^{q}(\mathbb{R}^n)},\qquad \frac{n}{p}=\frac{n}{q}-\alpha.$$
Now let $$\dot{W}^{\alpha, q}(\mathbb{R}^n)$$ denote the completion of the Schwartz class with respect to the norm 
$$\| f\|_{\dot{W}^{\alpha, q}(\mathbb{R}^n)}=\| D^\alpha f \|_{L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)}.$$

> My question is: is it true that 
>   $$\dot{W}^{\alpha, q}(\mathbb{R}^n)=\left\{f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)\ :\ \frac{n}{p}=\frac{n}{q}-\alpha\ \text{and}\ \| D^\alpha f \|_{L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)}<\infty \right\}?$$
>   Here $D^\alpha$ is taken in the tempered distributional sense.

---

$^{[1]}$ Let us not consider the case $\alpha <0$ for simplicity.

Comment: The quantity $\|D^\alpha f\|_{L^q}$ is a seminorm, not a norm. So, your definition of $\dot W^{\alpha,q}$ identifies functions that differ by a low-degree polynomial. Apart from this technicality, I think the statement is true. The set $\{f\in L^p \colon \dots\}$ is closed with respect to $\|D^\alpha\|_{L^q}$, and test functions are dense in it. So, it is a concrete model of the abstract completion.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday: I must admit that I do not fully understand your remark. Adding a polynomial to a Schwartz class function we do not obtain a Schwartz class function; therefore, $\|D^\alpha f\|_{L^q}$ defines a norm on the Schwartz class. Am I right?

Comment: Okay, my first two sentences can be omitted. Is there an issue with the equality of two spaces? Perhaps I am missing some subtlety.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday: I don't think there are issues, since it seems to me that your argument perfectly applies. I am asking because I find those "completion" things to be somewhat slippery (see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/883960/8157) ).

Comment: In the case $\alpha=n/2, q=2$ this would imply $\dot{H}^{n/2}\subset L^\infty$ which is not true.  It seems that it would be necessary for $\alpha<n/q$.  Which is sort of implied by what you wrote.

Comment: I have been kindly directed to the following arXiv paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.3970 in which Theorem 2.2 should contain the answer to the present question.

Comment: They correspond to the spaces if Sobolev functions that vanish at infinity https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4584970/understanding-the-space-d1-2-mathbbrn/4585092#4585092