# Understanding the space $D^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^N)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I have seem the following definition

$$D^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^N) := \{u \in L^{2^*}(\mathbb{R}^N) : |\nabla u| \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)\}.$$

I would like a reference that deals with this space deeply. I know this space is related with the best Sobolev constant. Specifically I'd like to know:

a) How this space was born?

b) This space has a norm or an inner product?

I know this space is nonempty, because from Brezis (Functional Analysis, Theorem 9.9) that exists a constant $c > 0$ such that
$$
\qquad |u|_{L^{2^*}(\mathbb{R}^N)} \leq c \, \|\nabla u \|_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^N)},\; \forall u \in W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^N).
$$
So, $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^N) \subset D^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ (is it right?)

I need to understand this space very well and so far I haven't found any reference with this. Any help or reference is very welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, $W^{1,2} \subset D^{1,2}$, and the difference of the two spaces is in the decay at infinity.

The first remark is that the two spaces are locally similar. If $u\in D^{1,2}$, then it is in $L^{2^*}$ and so in $L^2_{\text{loc}}$ (that is in $L^2(\Omega)$ for any compact $\Omega$). So the difference is at infinity (i.e. outside compact sets).

If you look at the behavior at infinity, the idea is that functions in $W^{1,2}$ have to be in $L^2$, which can be seen as a "faster decay" than $L^{2^*}$. For example, if you take locally nice radially decreasing functions such as $f(x) = \langle x\rangle^{-n}$ (where I wrote $\langle x\rangle = (1+|x|^2)^{1/2}$), then $f\in L^p(\Bbb R^N)$ if and only if $n > N/p$. So for example, if $N=3$ then $2^* = 6$, and $\langle x\rangle^{-1} \in D^{1,2}$ but $\langle x\rangle^{-1} \notin W^{1,2}$.

Now the crucial point is that the $L^2$ decay is not necessary to prove Sobolev inequalities. All what you need is $\nabla u \in L^2$ and $u$ "decays at infinity", because you still want to remove constants functions. But of course any space where Sobolev inequalities hold will be included in $D^{1,2}$. Hence, in some sense, $D^{1,2}$ is the **largest space where Sobolev inequalities hold**.

If you look for example in the book *Analysis* by Lieb and Loss (Sections 8.2 and 8.3) you will see that they actually initially define another space
$$
D^1 = \{u\in L^1_{\text{loc}}\mid \nabla u\in L^2, u \text{ vanishes at infinity}\}
$$
where $u$ "vanishes at infinity" means that for any $\lambda>0$, $\{x\mid u(x)>\lambda\}$ has finite measure. They then prove that the Sobolev inequality holds in $D^1$. Hence, $D^1 \subseteq D^{1,2}$. On the other hand, if $u\in D^{1,2}$, then it is in $L^{2^*}$, so in particular in $L^1_{\text{loc}}$. Moreover, if $\{x\mid u(x)>\lambda\}$ has infinite measure, then
$$
\int_{\Bbb R^N} |u|^{2^*} \geq \int_{\{x\mid u(x)>\lambda\}} |u|^{2^*} \geq \int_{\{x\mid u(x)>\lambda\}} |\lambda|^{2^*} = \infty.
$$
Hence $u\in D^1$, and so we conclude that
$$
D^1 = D^{1,2}.
$$
That is, $D^{1,2}$ is really just the space of functions decaying at infinity and such that $\nabla u\in L^2$.

This space is also sometimes called an homogeneous Sobolev space, and denoted by $\dot{H}^1$ and can also be defined as the completion of $C^\infty_c$ with respect to the $D^{1,2}$ norm, or by taking the quotient space so as to identify functions up to an addition of a constant function.

You can put the inner product
$$
\langle u,v\rangle = \int \nabla u\cdot\nabla v.
$$

Comment: Very nice, I didnt know this caracterization. Thank you very much.

Comment: LL 3.14, do you know a counter example that shows the gradient norm and usual norm in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ are not equivalent ?

Comment: Yes, that's the third paragraph ...